# Is it possible to use .d file to compile all dependent c files?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm new to make ifle 
I want to test certain function in my main. this function inside c files which has a LOT of dependencies that I cant even track

Is it possible to use the .d file for that .c file to compile my main with it to get this function working in my small application and the .d file gets all dependencies ?

I was thinking if it is possible to do something like

```
mymain.o : requiredfunctions.d mymain.c
```

Comment: When you say "dependencies", do you mean header files (e.g. `mymain.c` has a line '#include "kitchensink.h"')?

Comment: Actually, all c files that are required by "requiredfunctions.c" file to compile

Comment: I know that d file contains only header file, but I don't have a clue if I can use it someway to do the job or it'sn possible at all to do it

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: maybe, but you seem to misunderstand the relationship between source files, header files, object files and executables. I can explain in more detail if you like.

Comment: yes please, and post it as answer 
ty in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the relationship between source files, header files, object files and executable files.

Suppose we have several functions:

```
void alpha();
void beta();
void gamma();
void delta();
...
```

Each is declared in a **header file** (`alpha.h`) and defined in a **source file** (`alpha.c`). And suppose for now that these functions are independent; they do not call each other. Compiling one of them (to produce an **object file**) is easy:

```
gcc -c beta.c -o beta.o
```

(The "-c c -o o" is just a coincidence. The `-c` means "build an object file", and the `-o` means "here's how to name the result".)

We also have a function `void octopus()` that calls all of them. We declare it in a header, `octopus.h`:

```
// octopus.h
void octopus();
```

and define it in a source file, `octopus.c`:

```
#include "alpha.h"
#include "beta.h"
...
#include "omega.h"

void octopus()
{
  ... // calls alpha(), beta(), etc.
}
```

Producing the object file is easy:

```
gcc -c octopus.c -o octopus.o
```

Now suppose we have a file, `mymain.c`, which contains `main()` and invokes some functions:

```
#include "alpha.h"
#include "beta.h"

int main()
{
  alpha();
  beta();
  return 0;
}
```

Building the object file `mymain.o` is easy:

```
gcc -c mymain.c -o mymain.o
```

Building the **executable** `mymain` is slightly more difficult:

```
gcc mymain.o alpha.o beta.o -o mymain
```

If all of this is clear, then I can attempt to guess what you want. You want `main()` to call `octopus()`, and you want Make to build the executable for you *even though you do not know the list `alpha, beta,... omega`*, is that right?

**EDIT:** If you have the file `octopus.d`:

```
octopus.o: octopus.c alpha.h beta.h ... omega.h
```

you can turn it into the list of required object files:

```
alpha.o beta.o ... omega.o
```

by any of a number of methods. You could use sed from the command line:

```
sed 's/.*\.c //;s/h /o /g' octopus.d
```

or within a makefile you could use Make's text-manipulation functions:

```
OBJECTS := $(subst .h,.o,$(filter %.h, $(shell cat octopus.d)))
```

Comment: Exactly. this is what I want to do ? and what I only have is the .d file for the file octobus.c

Comment: @becks: If I show you how to turn `octopus.d` into the list `alpha.o beta.o ... omega.o` will that be enough? I ask because describing the entire chain would make this Answer much too long.

Comment: Yes, this would answer my question

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way of doing it:

```
foo.o : foo.c foo.d
    cc $< -o $@ -MF $(@:.o=.d)
    touch $(@:.o=.d)
    touch $Q

foo.d : ;

include foo.d
```

Not guaranteed to work as it is, just typed in without testing, but you get the idea.
Make sure that the compiler really produces the .d file in the proper format, further options might be necessary for your compiler. Some assemblers can also produce deps in the same way as compilers.

What's happening:

- We define the dep file as a secondary target. If it's missing or out
  of date, the recipe will be executed.
- After invoking the compiler, we touch first the dep file then the
  object. This fixes two issues: some compilers can't generate deps,
  and some set the dep file date to later than the object date. That
  would trigger unnecessary compilations.
- The empty recipe tells make that the file is generated by some
  other recipe, no need to panic when it's not there.
- And finally, we include the dep file.